# Не отправляются данные формы в БД.Что не так в коде?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте.
В таблицу **users** не отправляются данные из формы.
Использую локальный сервер Apache и базу данных MySQL (XAMPP).
Структура таблицы : user_id (AUTO_INCREMENT); login; password ; name; email;

Файл **register_html.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Страница регистрации</title>

</head>

<body>

Заполните форму:

<form method="post" action="">
    Логин: <input type="text" name="login" required><br>
    E-Mail:<input type="email" name="email" required><br>
    Пароль:<input type="password" name="password" required><br>
    Имя:<input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Регистрация"><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Очистить"><br>        
</form>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);



include_once "../connect.php";



if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];


    $result = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `email`, `password`, `name`) 
                                     VALUES ('".$login."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$name."')");
    if($result){
        echo 'Регистрация прошла успешно';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Ошибка';
        // выводите ошибку
    }
}
echo mysqli_error($link);

?>
```

Файл **connect.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb") or die("Unable to select database");
$db = mysqli_select_db($link,"mydb");
mysqli_query($link," SET NAMES 'utf8' ");

if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $link->connect_errno . ") " . $link->connect_error;
}
echo $link->host_info . "\n";

if (!$link || !$db){
    exit(mysqli_error());
}

?>
```

При вводе данных в форму и нажатия кнопки регистрации, форма просто обновляется на пустую, никаких ошибок при этом не появляется, так же как и прописанного в скрипте 'Регистрация прошла успешно'.Если без формы просто выполнить в ручную написанный текстовой запрос к бд - то в таблицу все записывается.Такое ощущение, что проблема именно в скрипте обработчика формы.Подскажите пожалуйста, что может являться причиной?Заранее спасибо.

Comment: INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`login\`, \`email\`, \`password\`, \`name\`) VALUES ('login22', 'mail@mail.ru', '123qwe', 'myname'); - попробуйте выполнить этот запрос в phpMyAdmin, выдаст ли он ошибку?

Comment: Нет,всё хорошо,всё в таблицу таким способом добавляется.

Способом через php файл, через mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ('losdfdsf', 'msdfsdl@mail.ru', '123sdfqwe', 'mynasdfme')") с подключением к бд тоже все данные записываются.

Answer (score 3):

Укажите в атрибуте action имя скрипта, который должен обрабатывать данные формы

```
<form method="post" action="register_html.php">
```

И заменить условие

```
if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
```

на

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
```

т.к. параметр `enter` с формы не передается

Comment: Указал, но к сожалению проблема осталась.

Comment: @Dust0 доуточнил ответ

Comment: поменял на if (isset($_POST['login'])) { , но все равно не помогает:(
Такое ощущение, что метод post вообще отключен.Может в php.ini что-то не так?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя есть ошибки, и не одна. И так:

***HTML***

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Логин: <input type="text" name="login" required><br>
    E-Mail:<input type="email" name="email" required><br>
    Пароль:<input type="password" name="password" required><br>
    Имя:<input type="text" name="name" required><br>

    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Регистрация"><br>

    <input type="reset" value="Очистить"><br>        
</form>
```

***файл где ты подключал connect.php***

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['enter'])):

      $login = $_POST['login'];//Надо чистить/проверять данные
      $email = $_POST['email'];//Надо чистить/проверять данные
      $password = $_POST['password'];//Надо чистить/проверять данные
      $name = $_POST['name'];//Надо чистить/проверять данные

      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb") 
               or die(mysqli_error($link));

      $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `email`, `password`, `name`) 
                 VALUES ('$login', '$email', '$password', '$name') "

      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

      if(mysqli_affected_rows($result)>0) 
         echo "Регистрация прошла успешно!";
      esle 
         echo "Что-то случилось, а вы не зарегистрировались";

endif;
```

***Ошибки:***

- `$db = mysqli_select_db($link,"mydb");` Ты уже указал название базы данных в подключении `$link`.
- В твоём случае, недопустимо использование процедурного и объектно-ориентированого стила вместе.
- Файл `connect.php` тебе вообще ненужен, ибо там только одна строчка подключения. А передать это подключение просто использовав `include_once` не получится.
- Все выводы ошибок и прекращения работы скрипта, типа: `echo mysqli_error($link);`, `if (!$link || !$db){
  exit(mysqli_error());}`, так же ненадо. Тебе в любом случае выдаст ошибку, и выповление прекратится.
- Отправка голых данных прямиком в БД это очень плохое начало! Всегда надо обрабатывать и очищать данные.
- Вот такая конструкция `'".$login."'` при создании запроса избыточна. Можно просто указать одинарные кавычки (*смотри мой пример*).

Это основное. Можна продолжать очень долго.

## UPDATE 1

Лучше всего, сделать один входной файл `index.php`, и через него направлять все действия. Принимает эти действия файл `controller.php`, он должен разбирать какие данные передать последнему файлу, который работает с базой данных, это `model.php`. В одном файле **очень** нежелательно совмещать HTML и PHP код (разве что для вывода информации).

Кажется мне, что учишься по видеоуроках Евгения Попова:) Если нет, то он для начинающих самое то. Объяснять он умеет, но качество написания кода, оставляет желать лучшего.

## UPDATE 2#

1. Создай на сервере новую папку для тестового проекта, назови её, скажем, `test-project`.
2. После того как создал папку проекта, перегрузи сервер.
3. В этой папке создай два файла `index.php` и `action.php`, ниже напишу их содержимое.
4. После того как создал файлы, открой в браузере этот проект (я не знаю как в xampp'е прописывается путь к локальному сайту)

***Файл `index.php`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index File for test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstInput" placeholder="first" value="">
    <input type="text" name="secondInput" placeholder="second" value="">
    <input type="text" name="thirdInput" placeholder="third" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="actionButton" value="RUN ACTION">
</form>


</body>
</html>

<?php if(include_once 'action.php') echo 'yes'; ?>
```

***Файл `action.php`***

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['actionButton'])):
      echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
      echo "</pre>";
endif;
```

Все эти параметры в файле `php.ini` о которых ты спрашивал, не нужно изменять/удалять и всё остальное. Сервер уже настроен для работы. Разве что у тебя есть особые пожелания и замечания, но это не твой случай :)

Всё, пробуй. Отпишешь.

Comment: Здравствуйте,большое спасибо вам за ответ и за советы, мне как новичку это очень полезно.Сделал всё как вы написали, но всё равно не помогло :(

Создал сейчас файлы test.html и test.php, в test.html такая форма:

<form method="post" action="test.php">
    Имя:<input type="text" name="name" ><br>

    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Вперед" /><br>

    <input type="reset" value="Очистить" ><br>

А в test.php :
print_r($_POST);

var_dump($_POST);

При отправке формы выводится Array ( ) array(0) { }.Получается, что post метод у меня вообще не обработался?

Comment: @Dust0 Попробуйте убрать `action='test.php'`. А файл `test.html` переименуйте в `index.php` или любое другое название, главное расширение поставьте `.php`. И в этом файле сверху попробуйте подключить `include 'test.php'`, Я чуть позже сделаю по вашему примеру и покажу вам, если ничего не получится. И еще, у формы надеюсь закрывающий тег есть:))

Comment: Попробовал, но всё равно не выходит.У формы да, тег закрывающийся есть,сюда просто скопировал криво) Как вы считаете может ли быть проблема в php.ini?Посмотрел в нём некоторые параметры, стоит register_globals=Off и enable_post_data_reading = Off;Стоит ли еще  что-то там посмотреть или не в данном файле дело? А вообще,как поставил xampp,ничего не менял ни в каких файлах.

Comment: Нет, в `php.ini` ничего не надо менять. Там все настроено как должно. Я пользуюсь [Open Server](http://open-server.ru/), лично мне он больше всего понравился, работать одно удовольствие:) Ну ладно. Я сейчас добавлю несколько строк в своём ответе, что надо сделать.

Comment: Всё сделал и наконец нашел проблему!))Все дело было в PhpStorm'е, когда я через него в браузере открывал проект, например,http://localhost/test-project/index.php, то он дописывал к localhost'y что-то вроде этого http://localhost:62233 и после index.php были строки.В браузере в целом выходил примерно такой путь:http://localhost:62233/test-project/index.php?_isdf=gp3ts078dsfbcvcbmdaawe7cv0.В этом как оказалось и была проблема......Когда я самостоятельно ввел в браузере http://localhost/test-project/index.php без посторонних символов - всё заработало))

Comment: В базу данных теперь всё так же стало записываться)Такие вот пироги)А все дело в вашей строке "После того как создал файлы, открой в браузере этот проект(я не знаю как в xampp'е прописывается путь к локальному сайту)" - обратил на это внимание решил прописать всё в ручную и вот и заработало всё)Так что спасибо вам, без ваших подсказок еще наверное долго бы искал проблему :) Такая вот мелочь стала такой проблемой, будет мне уроком)

Comment: @Dust0 Наконец-то! Не за что :)